# how can i capture a rotated event from backend for an xml configuration in log4j2 2.20.2?

Tags: log4j2

I am currently trying to capture a rollover event for every minute and apply business logic to the rollover file. I have an xml with a RollingFile configured and within the policies I have a specific plugin to capture the rotation which extends from AbstractTriggeringPolicy but I can't even get the file to rotate per minute. The idea is to do it for every day but I use the rollover per minute to test...

this is my code:

```
---- XML ----

<Configuration status="warn" name="MyApp">
  <Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="logs/app.log" filePattern="logs/app-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm}.log">
      <PatternLayout>
        <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
      <Policies>
        <XXXX_TriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true" />
      </Policies>
    </RollingFile>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="error">
      <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>

---- Java ----

/**
 * Rolls a file over based on time.
 */
@Plugin(name = "XXXX_TriggeringPolicy", category = Core.CATEGORY_NAME, printObject = true)
public final class XXXX_TriggeringPolicy extends AbstractTriggeringPolicy {


    public static class Builder implements org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.Builder<XXXX_TriggeringPolicy> {

        @PluginBuilderAttribute
        private int interval = 1;

        @PluginBuilderAttribute
        private boolean modulate = false;

        @PluginBuilderAttribute
        private int maxRandomDelay = 0;

        @Override
        public XXXX_TriggeringPolicy build() {
            final long maxRandomDelayMillis = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(maxRandomDelay);
            return new XXXX_TriggeringPolicy(interval, modulate, maxRandomDelayMillis);
        }

        public int getInterval() {
            return interval;
        }

        public boolean isModulate() {
            return modulate;
        }

        public int getMaxRandomDelay() {
            return maxRandomDelay;
        }

        public Builder withInterval(final int interval){
            this.interval = interval;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withModulate(final boolean modulate){
            this.modulate = modulate;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withMaxRandomDelay(final int maxRandomDelay){
            this.maxRandomDelay = maxRandomDelay;
            return this;
        }

    }

    private long nextRolloverMillis;
    private final int interval;
    private final boolean modulate;
    private final long maxRandomDelayMillis;

    private RollingFileManager manager;

    private XXXX_TriggeringPolicy(final int interval, final boolean modulate, final long maxRandomDelayMillis) {
        this.interval = interval;
        this.modulate = modulate;
        this.maxRandomDelayMillis = maxRandomDelayMillis;
    }

    public int getInterval() {
        return interval;
    }

    public long getNextRolloverMillis() {
        return nextRolloverMillis;
    }

    /**
     * Initializes the policy.
     * @param aManager The RollingFileManager.
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(final RollingFileManager aManager) {
        this.manager = aManager;
        long current = aManager.getFileTime();
        if (current == 0) {
            current = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }

        // LOG4J2-531: call getNextTime twice to force initialization of both prevFileTime and nextFileTime
        aManager.getPatternProcessor().getNextTime(current, interval, modulate);
        aManager.getPatternProcessor().setTimeBased(true);

        nextRolloverMillis = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(0, 1 + maxRandomDelayMillis)
                + aManager.getPatternProcessor().getNextTime(current, interval, modulate);
    }

    /**
     * Determines whether a rollover should occur.
     * @param event   A reference to the currently event.
     * @return true if a rollover should occur.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean isTriggeringEvent(final LogEvent event) {
        final long nowMillis = event.getTimeMillis();
        if (nowMillis >= nextRolloverMillis) {
            nextRolloverMillis = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(0, 1 + maxRandomDelayMillis)
                    + manager.getPatternProcessor().getNextTime(nowMillis, interval, modulate);
            manager.getPatternProcessor().setCurrentFileTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
            // TODO:
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    @PluginBuilderFactory
    public static XXXX_TriggeringPolicy.Builder newBuilder() {
        return new Builder();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "XXXX_TriggeringPolicy(nextRolloverMillis=" + nextRolloverMillis + ", interval=" + interval
                + ", modulate=" + modulate + ")";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are extending the wrong component: the component that performs rollovers is called [`RolloverStrategy`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/rolling/RolloverStrategy.html). Your rollover logic should go there.

A [`TriggeringPolicy`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/rolling/TriggeringPolicy.html) is just one of the methods to call `RolloverStrategy#rollover`. Some rollovers are not even triggered by a `TriggeringPolicy` (cf. [`CronTriggeringPolicy`](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/2.x/log4j-core/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/rolling/CronTriggeringPolicy.java)).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for the approach! This is my final code and it works as per the requirements.

```
// --- XML ---
<Configuration status="warn" name="MyApp">
<Appenders>
     <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="logs/app.log" filePattern="logs/app-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm}.log">
           <PatternLayout>
                 <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
           </PatternLayout>
           <Policies>
                 <XXXX_TriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true" />
           </Policies>
           <XXXXXXRolloverStrategy />
     </RollingFile>
</Appenders>
</Configuration>

// --- JAVA ---
// The trigger. It allows me to launch the rotated strategy based on the time that I specify.

@Plugin(name = "XXXX_TriggeringPolicy", category = Core.CATEGORY_NAME, printObject = true)
enter code herepublic class XXXX_TriggeringPolicy extends AbstractTriggeringPolicy {
private long nextRolloverMillis;

private final int interval;

private final boolean modulate;

private final long maxRandomDelayMillis;

private RollingFileManager manager;

private LogEvent logEvent;

private ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService;

public static class Builder implements org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.Builder < XXXX_TriggeringPolicy > {
    @PluginBuilderAttribute
    private int interval = 1;

    @PluginBuilderAttribute
    private boolean modulate = false;

    @PluginBuilderAttribute

    private int maxRandomDelay = 0;



    @Override

    public XXXX_TriggeringPolicy build() {

        final long maxRandomDelayMillis = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(maxRandomDelay);

        return new XXXX_TriggeringPolicy(interval, modulate, maxRandomDelayMillis);

    }



    public int getInterval() {

        return interval;

    }



    public boolean isModulate() {

        return modulate;

    }



    public int getMaxRandomDelay() {

        return maxRandomDelay;

    }



    public Builder withInterval(final int interval) {

        this.interval = interval;

        return this;

    }



    public Builder withModulate(final boolean modulate) {

        this.modulate = modulate;

        return this;

    }



    public Builder withMaxRandomDelay(final int maxRandomDelay) {

        this.maxRandomDelay = maxRandomDelay;

        return this;

    }



}



private XXXX_TriggeringPolicy(final int interval, final boolean modulate, final long maxRandomDelayMillis) {

    this.interval = interval;

    this.modulate = modulate;

    this.maxRandomDelayMillis = maxRandomDelayMillis;

}



public int getInterval() {

    return interval;

}



public long getNextRolloverMillis() {

    return nextRolloverMillis;

}



@Override

public void initialize(final RollingFileManager aManager) {

    this.manager = aManager;

    long current = aManager.getFileTime();

    if (current == 0) {

        current = System.currentTimeMillis();

    }



    // LOG4J2-531: call getNextTime twice to force initialization of both

    // prevFileTime and nextFileTime

    aManager.getPatternProcessor().getNextTime(current, interval, modulate);

    aManager.getPatternProcessor().setTimeBased(true);



    nextRolloverMillis = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(0, 1 + maxRandomDelayMillis)

        +
        aManager.getPatternProcessor().getNextTime(current, interval, modulate);



    logEvent = new LogEventRollOver();

}



@Override

public boolean isTriggeringEvent(final LogEvent event) {

    final long nowMillis = event.getTimeMillis();

    if (nowMillis >= nextRolloverMillis) {

        nextRolloverMillis = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(0, 1 + maxRandomDelayMillis)

            +
            manager.getPatternProcessor().getNextTime(nowMillis, interval, modulate);

        manager.getPatternProcessor().setCurrentFileTime(System.currentTimeMillis());

        return true;

    }

    return false;

}



@PluginBuilderFactory

public static XXXX_TriggeringPolicy.Builder newBuilder() {

    return new Builder();

}



@Override

public String toString() {

    return "XXXX_TriggeringPolicy(nextRolloverMillis=" + nextRolloverMillis + ", interval=" + interval

        +
        ", modulate=" + modulate + ")";

}



private void proccessRollover() {

    ((LogEventRollOver) logEvent).setTimeMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

    this.manager.checkRollover(logEvent);

}
}


// The strategy. The rollover is done by extending a default policy and I apply my business logic after the rotated.



@Plugin(name = "XXXXXXRolloverStrategy", category = "Core", printObject = true)
public class XXXXXXRolloverStrategy extends DefaultRolloverStrategy {



protected static final Logger statusLogger = StatusLogger.getLogger();



protected static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(XXXXXXRolloverStrategy.class);



private static final int MIN_WINDOW_SIZE = 1;

private static final int DEFAULT_WINDOW_SIZE = 7;



protected XXXXXXRolloverStrategy(int minIndex, int maxIndex, boolean useMax, int compressionLevel, StrSubstitutor strSubstitutor) {

    super(minIndex, maxIndex, useMax, compressionLevel, strSubstitutor, null, false, null);

}



@PluginFactory

public static XXXXXXRolloverStrategy createStrategy(@PluginAttribute("max") final String max, @PluginAttribute("min") final String min, @PluginAttribute("fileIndex") final String fileIndex, @PluginAttribute("compressionLevel") final String compressionLevelStr, @PluginConfiguration final Configuration config) {

    final boolean useMax = fileIndex == null ? true : fileIndex.equalsIgnoreCase("max");

    int minIndex;

    if (min != null) {

        minIndex = Integer.parseInt(min);

        if (minIndex < 1) {

            LOGGER.error("Minimum window size too small. Limited to " + MIN_WINDOW_SIZE);

            minIndex = MIN_WINDOW_SIZE;

        }

    } else {

        minIndex = MIN_WINDOW_SIZE;

    }

    int maxIndex;

    if (max != null) {

        maxIndex = Integer.parseInt(max);

        if (maxIndex < minIndex) {

            maxIndex = minIndex < DEFAULT_WINDOW_SIZE ? DEFAULT_WINDOW_SIZE : minIndex;

            LOGGER.error("Maximum window size must be greater than the minimum windows size. Set to " + maxIndex);

        }

    } else {

        maxIndex = DEFAULT_WINDOW_SIZE;

    }

    final int compressionLevel = Integers.parseInt(compressionLevelStr, Deflater.DEFAULT_COMPRESSION);



    return new XXXXXXRolloverStrategy(minIndex, maxIndex, useMax, compressionLevel, config.getStrSubstitutor());

}



public RolloverDescription rollover(final RollingFileManager manager) {

    RolloverDescription rolloverDescription = null;

    LOGGER.info("el tamaño de auditDaily.log es de: " + String.valueOf(manager.getFileSize()));



    if (manager.getFileSize() > 0) {

        RolloverDescription rd = super.rollover(manager);



        FileRenameAction oldRenameAction = (FileRenameAction) rd.getSynchronous();

        FileRenameAction newRenameAction = new FileRenameAction(oldRenameAction.getSource(), oldRenameAction.getDestination(), true);

        rolloverDescription = new RolloverDescriptionImpl(rd.getActiveFileName(), rd.getAppend(), newRenameAction, rd.getAsynchronous());



        Thread threadLogSigner = new LogXXXXX(newRenameAction.getDestination());

        threadLogXXXXX.start();

    } else {

        logger.info(Language.getResCoreGeneral("logAL007"));

    }

    return rolloverDescription;

}



private class LogXXXXX extends Thread {



    private File destination;



    private Logger signerLogger = LogManager.getLogger(LogXXXXX.class);



    public LogXXXXX(File destination) {

        this.destination = destination;

    }



    public final void run() {

        // TODO: I SEARCH MY FILE ROLLOVER HERE AND APPLY MY BUSINESS LOGIC TO IT.

    }

}
}
```